# Eclipse reading wrong import on start up

Tags: java, eclipse

When ever I started Eclipse a maven project called always has an error - Its kinda hard to explain - see the image

Comment: It means that class that you are trying to import is not available..that is not resolved by the compiler...is it available in your project...

Comment: Try building the project. Most probably maven will download the dependecies.

Comment: What's your question? What is the context? What have you done, in what situation do you encounter this? Details, please.

Comment: The class is available in my project.. I have built it before just fine.. Leistungsabfall answer fixed it but I think it will show up again like it did yestarday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class that you`re trying to import **does** exist, it is an eclipse failure.

`Project -> Clean` should fix it.

Comment: Worked. This has happend twice, any ideas why its showing up like that?

Comment: To be honest I don't know what is causing this, but it seems like mostly eclipse has this kind of problem sometimes. By calling `Project -> Clean` already compiled files are removed so that you can do a new build.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not added proper jar in the classpath . please check if classpath is correct or not.